# Adding blank lines between filtered datasets in excel

Tags: excel, filter, insert, blank-line

I have a highly filtered data set in excel, (start with about 8000 rows - after filter about 250) with lots of formatting. Is there a way to add a blank line in between my filtered out rows? [image]

In the image I would like a line added before or after 589, then 592, then 595 and so on. I can't un-filter the data because I would lose lots of work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select all the cells
2. Press f5, select special
3. Select **Visible cells only**, press ok
4. Right click on one of the cells and click insert row

This will insert a row above each filtered row.

If there are two visible rows next to each other (row 19 and row 20) it will insert two rows above this group (which is likely not what you want but I still think its your best solution.  Those rows you could adjust the rows manually.

Answer (score 1):

Short Cut Key:

- To select individual rows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>(semicolon)
- To add row: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>(Plus)